# How to translate "X and Y are wrongly matched"

Tags: english-to-german

I would like to translate following sentence, but I could not decide which word go together with "matched". There are five options and one of them is wrongly matched.

> In option A are the learning style and its definition wrongly matched.
>   *(Bei Option A sind der Lernstil und dessen Definition falsch abgestimmt.)*

actual context as follows:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I could. I'll add actual context.It contain a learning style and its definition. Please check my post body again.

Comment: *... sind falsch aufeinander abgestimmt* und es wäre ok. Was sagt denn das Wörterbuch? Wieso genügt dessen Information nicht?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I propose to use the verb *zuordnen* like in

> Bei welchem der folgenden Punkte ist dem jeweiligen Lernstil die falsche Definition zugeordnet?

Answer (score 4):

Another possible translation:

> English: In option A are the learning style and its definition wrongly matched.
>   German: In Option A passen der Lernstil und seine Definition nicht zueinander.

"*wrongly matched*" would be translated as "*nicht zueinander passen*"

As it is a little informal I would go with [Matthias version](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/32674/10909).

Comment: I don't see "nicht zueinander passen" as the least bit informal. It does, however, lack the activity present in the English original and in Matthias' answer (which maybe doesn't matter in the example)